# Sitecore on MAC machine using Docker

Tags: docker

Has anyone installed Sitecore on MAC machine using docker? Steps provided by Sitecore is compatible to Windows machine but not MAC. Few of the Frontend developers are comfortable with MAC machine and not wanted to move to Windows. JSS is installed on their local machine and working fine but not Sitecore.

Comment: To do it on a Mac you must first install a Windows OS on it (in a Virtual Machine). Via something like Fusion or VirtualBox. Then proceed to follow Windows installation instructions inside your VM. Good luck.

Comment: I had lots of problems with Docker and Hyper-V on a VM on a Mac. I am now thinking I'd like to try spinning up services that can run in Linux on docker on the mac like solr, traefik, redis, and sql server. and then just run the IIS/Windows required containers in docker in a VM along with the dev environment. I just have to work out the networking aspects of that.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore uses Windows-based Docker containers.
You could not run Windows containers directly on OS X.

You have 2 options:

1. Install [Bootcamp](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp) on your machine and allow dual boot between OS X and Windows  10
2. You can install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)(or any other software that allows you to use virtual machines). And then install Windows as a virtual machine.

Then you need to follow [official Sitecore instructions](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/developer-tools/run-your-first-sitecore-instance.html) for Windows

Comment: How efficient is this with m1 and m2 processors? Does everything work properly?

Comment: I haven't tried. And, actually, don't recommend it...

Comment: For Apple M chips check related question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/32424/2492

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend trying this https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine as a workaround that helps you launch a windows container via a VirtualBox or VMware.

Short description:

> This Vagrant environment creates a "Docker Machine" to work on your
> MacBook with Windows containers. You can easily switch between Docker
> Desktop Linux containers and the Windows containers.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.

Installed VirtualBox, and Windows 10. Then I was able to install Sitecore, as it will take Windows containers only.