# Sitecore development using MacBook pro with m1 or m2 processors

Tags: development

If anyone tried to use MacBook pro with m1 or m2 processor please share your experience as this is my only factor for getting a windows laptop unfortunately. I would like to know if everything works perfectly on m1 and m2 processors with windows.

Comment: Just install Windows 10 Pro on your mac and you should be fine
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468

Comment: I know how to install windows on Mac, but my question is, did you face any trouble while doing sitecore development on macbook pro with m1 or m2 processors? Because of the limitation with new processors with windows

Comment: If you're planning on using docker inside windows, the m1 and m2 processors don't support nested virtualization.

Comment: Bootcamp doesn't work and probably will never work on Apple M chips. Recently Microsoft announced official support for Windows 11 Pro and Enterprise with Parallels Desktop. But this is ARM version of Windows, without support of nested virtualization, so running Docker may not be possible. Source:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/options-for-using-windows-11-with-mac-computers-with-apple-m1-and-m2-chips-cd15fd62-9b34-4b78-b0bc-121baa3c568c